# Legend mismatch data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use this code but get 2 problems:
1 - an extra crop in the legend
2 - mismatching legend

```html
#datalocation
scdata=read.csv("SeedcountR.csv")
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

##Group the data by Rotation
scdata$rotation[scdata$Rot.Trt %in% c("C2", "S2")]<-"TwoYear"
scdata$rotation[scdata$Rot.Trt %in% c("C3", "S3", "O3")]<-"ThreeYear"
scdata$rotation[scdata$Rot.Trt %in% c("C4", "S4", "O4", "A4")]<-"FourYear"

##Plot

scdata$rotation <- factor(scdata$rotation, levels = c("TwoYear", "ThreeYear", "FourYear"))
ggplot(scdata, aes(Rot.Herb, Count, fill=Crop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(~rotation, scales = "free_x", space="free_x")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  ggtitle("Weed seedbank by subplot")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  xlab("Rotation systems and Herbicide regimes (L = Low herbicide regime, C = Conventional herbicide regime)")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Corn C", "Corn L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L", "Corn C", "Corn L", "Oat C", "Oat L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L", "Alfalfa C", "Alfalfa L", "Corn C", "Corn L", "Oat C", "Oat L", "Soybean C", "Soybean L"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  ylab("Weed seed count")
```

[image]

Please find the result plot and data here
[Data and plot](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jb6gjznyw2q16mx/AADcNKiicqkoHxpFYIsaTgk9a?dl=0)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean `2 problems: 1 - an extra crop in the legend 2 - mismatching legend`? This description seems too broad to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot is just plotting what you have in your data - you need to check and clean your data. Take a look at the different levels of "crop" in the data.frame:

```
> levels(scdata$Crop)
[1] ""        "alfalfa" "corn"    "oat"     "soybean"
```

That's why you have an "extra" blank crop in the legend. You can see the relevant lines with:

```
scdata[scdata$Crop=="",]
```

Which'll show you that you have read in a set of summary/total/blank lines at the end of your CSV file.

I'd also suggest not setting the x-axis labels directly in the ggplot call, especially if you have lots of them. It can easily cause mislabelling problems, that will be very hard to spot, if the data are not in the order you expect. I don't know exactly what fields you want, but use things like `paste` and `sprintf` to set up your labels in advance.